# Magento Ajax Shipping Calculation?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento

See http://www.gymandfitness.com.au, goto a general product and on the top left of the product info section theres a field where you enter your local POSTCODE and and it instantly gets the shipping cost without refreshing the page.

Is there a good Magento Module that will do that?

Or How would I go about making something like that? I'm assuming its just a ajax query to the PHP function that calculates shipping and returns the value in a box on the page?

Where would I need to reference to do that you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Your assumption about ajax seems pretty reasonable. Have you tried it? What have you coded so far?

Comment: @nnnnnn: No code as of yet, I have a localhost magento installation but am still somewhat unsure where to go form there. My experience thus far with magento coding is minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cases where shipping cost depends on much more than the postal code.

For instance, weight and size of the package(s) can drastically change the rate.

Similarly, a customer could have a choice between 7-day, overnight, etc. delivery methods.

That being said, look into major shipping providers' APIs. USPS, FedEx, UPS all have them available.

Build a script that will take the postal code from the customer, wrap it and send it to the shipper's API, and return the resulted cost as JSON. At that point, you can display it back via jQuery or whatever you're using.

Comment: Regrettably the current shipping provider used does not have an API, I can only rely on the shipping rules set in place by magento. I also presume the function that calculates the shipping also takes the product information into account or id send it with the ajax request to the function.

Again the shipping company used does not support different delivery methods as you refer to them or 'we' purposefully do not support them.

Comment: In that case, I would write an API of my own to process the custom rules and give the result back as JSON. Then the process remains the same as the one I described above, except it is your own API you're talking to.

Comment: True true.. this could be interesting.